# updating sum of a column in datagrid view every time a mew record is entered

Tags: wpf

I have created a form with data grid view..where there is a column called rate.and a label called grand total.I want the label to display the total of rate column every time i open the form. also i want to update the label every time i enter a new record.Could anyone help me with the coding.

Comment: Please post WPF snippet of form/grid + Data structure. You should be handling the update in your Viewmodel

Answer (score 0):

the source datagridview.Itemssource should be ObservableCollection and use the CollectionChanged event:

```
ObservableCollection<T> data = new ObservableCollection<T>();

            data.CollectionChanged += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
                {
                    YourLabel.Content = Your Sum ...;
                }
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are fetching values from database...then call that function in which you are fetching record from database after insertion of new record..